# SmartTabs runtime events error

Tags: delphi, runtime, delphi-xe2

This is the part of code where I get the error:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, cefvcl, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, ceflib,
  Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ImgList, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage, Vcl.Buttons, JvSpeedButton, Themes,
  JvExComCtrls, JvComCtrls, JvgPage, Vcl.ToolWin, JvToolBar, Vcl.Menus,
  Vcl.Mask, JvExMask, JvToolEdit, JvExButtons, JvButtons, rkSmartTabs, rkAeroTabs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    {....}
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure addnewtab (Sender: TObject);
    procedure closetab (Sender: TObject);

private
  { Private declarations }
public
  { Public declarations }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{....}

procedure TForm1.closetab (Sender: TObject);
var
  smarttabs: TrkAeroTabs;
begin
  smarttabs := Sender as TrkAeroTabs;
  smarttabs.DeleteTab(smarttabs.ActiveTab);
end;

procedure TForm1.addnewtab (Sender: TObject);
var
  smarttabs: TrkAeroTabs;
begin
  smarttabs := Sender as TrkAeroTabs;
  smarttabs.AddTab('New Tab');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
with TrkAeroTabs.Create(self) do
  begin
    OnCloseTab := closetab;  //***ERROR HERE***
    OnAddClick := addnewtab;
    Parent := Self;
    Align := alClient;
    AddTab('New Tab');
    if ClassType = TrkAeroTabs then
    begin
      ColorBackground := clBlack;
      with Self do
      begin
        GlassFrame.Top     := 25;
        GlassFrame.Enabled := True;
      end;
    end;
    ShowButton   := True;
    AllowTabDrag := True;
  end;
end;
```

this is the error:

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(90): E2009 Incompatible types: 'Parameter lists differ'
```

addnewtab() works fine. I do not understand why closetab() does not work. Thanks.

Comment: May I suggest you try TChromeTabs (http://www.easy-ip.net/tchrometabs.html) instead? It's completely free, has many more features than SmartTabs and is still actively being developed. It also comes with a very comprehensive demo application.

Comment: @norgepaul: +1. If I am not mistaken you are (one of) the developer(s) of TChromeTabs. It is customary on SO to disclose that. Not everybody will have seen your previous messages about the component and know it. Oh and disclosure need not be anything special. Simply inserting my/our as in 'try my/our TChromeTabs' should be more than enough.

Comment: @MarjanVenema - Good point, I'll make sure I do that in the future. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @norgepaul Thanks, very good component.

Comment: @norgepaul After i compile ChromeTabs_XE2_R.bpl, there is no install button in the menu.

Comment: @giacomokingpatermo - There are two packages, one runtime and one design time. First compile ChromeTabs_XE2_R, then install ChromeTabs_XE2_D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *doesn't work* because the event is declared with a type different from TNotifyEvent, and your method parameters have to match to what is declared in the type used (number and type of parameters).

Navigate to the event declaration and you find this:

```
  TrkAeroTabs = class(TCustomControl)
  ..
  published
  ..
    property OnCloseTab: TOnTabCloseEvent read FOnCloseTab write FOnCloseTab;
```

Then, navigate to the TOnTabCloseEvent declaration and you find this:

```
TOnTabCloseEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer;
  var Close: Boolean) of object;
```

So, you have to declare your method like this:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
    procedure closetab (Sender: TObject; Index: Integer; var CanClose: Boolean);


procedure TForm1.closetab (Sender: TObject; Index: Integer; var CanClose: Boolean);
var
  smarttabs: TrkAeroTabs;
begin
  smarttabs := Sender as TrkAeroTabs;
  smarttabs.DeleteTab(smarttabs.ActiveTab);
end;
```

And now, you can successfully assign this method to the event.